# Opposite boolean value of accessed model class' variable in Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

If i'm in template mode and I want to access the oposite of a model class' variable, how would I go about that?

**For example I tried:***

```
@(myForm: Form[MyFormClass])
<input type="text" disabled="!@myForm.get.isSelected>
```

where isSelected is a boolean variable

However, I receive the error:

```
`identifier' expected but `!' found
```

I looked around but couldn't find anything..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The @ symbol is just a special character that tells the compiler that Scala code is starting.
So, in your code what you are saying is output the ! first, and then process some scala.

What you should be able to do is

```
@{!myForm.get.isSelected}
```

As this is is telling scala compiler to execute `!myForm.get.isSelected` as a statement (because of the braces), and not just to output the value directly.